# Compile app with OpenCV for Axis camera

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to create an application which will use some modules from OpenCV and compile it for an Axis camera (M3114 preferably). The whole OpenCV is too big and cannot fit in the camera's memory. How can I select some specific modules (instead of compiling all of them)?

Comment: you can tick off anything non-nessecary with cmake-gui(maybe you only need core,imgproc and highgui), specify a release-build or call 'strip' on the binaries

Comment: you can build statically linked libs, so when you compile your program, you end up with one big binary chunk, which is around 8-10mb usually

Comment: how do i run cmake-gui? also, the camera's memory is less than 7MB, so the binary has to be smaller than that